# Newbie pinout questions for LM360N

Tags: voltage, comparator, pinout

For my first project, I'm trying to make an LED light up when the voltage from a variable source reaches a certain point (13V in my exiting circuit).

To do this, I'm going to take the output from a 5V voltage regulator (L7805) and and run it to an LM360N comparitor, and then compare that voltage with the output of a voltage divider from my source voltage.

The problem I'm currently having is that I can't seem to figure out the pinout for my LM360N. It's a 14 pin DIP format and all the examples I see online are 8 pin SOIC. Can anyone offer some insight?

Comment: Are you certain that you have an LM360N?  Both National and TI show the LM360 as only available in 8 pin packages.

Comment: I only found a single image of a LM360N-14 via Google, and it was an [obvious counterfeit chip](http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/32262056941/LM360N-14.jpg_350x350.jpg). I think you have a fake.

Comment: Is there a subtle glue line?

Comment: Maybe you have a LM339 quad comparator? That one does come in DIP14. If you're having trouble reading the chip try using a high-power LED flashlight and vary the angles of the light.

Comment: Writing on the top of the chip says, "/822 LM360M"

Comment: @SonnyBoy: Out of curiosity, did you buy this recently or is it a pull/recycled part you fond in some device? There hasn't been a chip with that marking on the market for at least 20 years...

Comment: @RespawnedFluff - Got it on eBay. Must be an old part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This 1994 datasheet](https://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/sites/default/files/ees/files/NI/pdfs/00/57/DS005707.pdf) shows the National Semi LM360 in 14 pin Ceramic Dip (Package J, not M). The pin out shows Pins 1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14 are NC (Non-Connects). The rest match the 8 pin Dip and soic pinouts, with pin 3 matching pin 1 of the smaller packages, in physical location.

Comment: Still... I'm guessing the one the OP has is even older than that datasheet, because there's no DIP14 for LM360M in it... but only for LM160J-14/883 (ceramic).

Comment: Good catch @RespawnedFluff. I'm hoping that the pinout matches for Op's use at least.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: LM360N-14 definitely existed as did LM360J-14... around 1973: http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Scans-062/DSA2IH00119655.pdf (as did LM260 of which you can't find any images in google either) Oddly enough LM360M-14 is not mentioned there... but it's almost surely the same.